# highlight with elasticsearch exists query

Tags: elasticsearch

Actually what I want to achieve is like when I execute a exists query I should get all the data that is present in that field to behighlighted.
Example query:

```
{
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "timeout":"5s",
   "highlight":{
      "require_field_match":true,
      "fields":{
         "*":{
            
         }
      },
      "pre_tags":[
         "<b>"
      ],
      "post_tags":[
         "</b>"
      ],
      "max_analyzed_offset":200974
   },
   "query":{
            "exists":{
               "field":"RegId"
            }
         }
}
```

For the above query, I want to get all the documents which have values in the field **RegId**, those values should be highlighted.
Currently, I can get all the docs with values in the field **RegId**. But those values are not highlighted.
Thank you..

Comment: For Elasticsearch to highlight you need to enter the term. Why do you want to do it like this?

Comment: @rabbitbr Thank you for answering. Because I want to get the data in that field If that field exists.